# Blazor PWA Components Styling with css

Tags: css, blazor, progressive-web-apps, isolation

There is this problem i have working with .net5 blazor PWA project.

I have two css file. One is created by the blazor project app.css and the other css file is a css isolated file. I don't know if it is specificly css isolation problem but the issue is i can't style blazor html elements with isolated css file, like editform, inputtext...

In my css file i have this css lines below:

```
editform {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0rem 5rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.text-area inputtext {
    background: none;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}
```

Well, I had my research but no luck so far. Do i make something wrong here?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: from the  Ms docs : By default, CSS isolation only applies to the component you associate with the format {COMPONENT NAME}.razor.css, where the placeholder {COMPONENT NAME} is usually the component name. To apply changes to a child component, use the ::deep combinator to any descendant elements in the parent component's .razor.css file

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#child-component-support

Comment: Thanks for your reply, while i wrote the answer didn't see your comment. That's what i found out too. Thank you for your time, preciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the solution.

Blazor custom elements(component is the right terminology I don't know) renders to its related HTML elements. For example, `<EditForm>` renders to `<form>` element.

So, in order to access rendered element we need `::deep` .

The css style for editform in my question becomes:

```
form, ::deep from{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
flex-direction: column;
padding: 0rem 5rem;
overflow: hidden;
}

.text-area ::deep input {
background: none;
outline: none;
border: none;
}
```

If having a class in that deep element I used following code:

```
::deep .customClass
```

This solution is worked for me but i wonder if there is some other way to style blazor custom elements. Because blazor uses this component `<app></app>` .net core 3.1. And if you check the css file in the project you can see the styling is happening with the code below just like normal HTML element.

```
app {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

This confuses me. Any information about this topic much appreciated.